# Testing the null hypothesis of zero skew

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I need to test the null hypothesis that my steady returns have a zero skewness with a confidence level of 95%. Do you have any ideas which formula I can take for this kind of test ? I tried the Agostino test for skewness, but think it's not the best way, because I can't set a confidence level.

```
library(moments)
?agostino.test
```

Comment: this question might be better suited for StackExchange (https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, all you have to do is compare the p-value from `agostino.test()` (which can be extracted from the returned object) with a specified alpha, i.e.

```
library(moments)
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(1000)
a <- agostino.test(x)
a$p.value < 0.05  ## FALSE, fail to reject
```

(In case it's not clear, the 0.05 here is 1-(your confidence level)=1-0.95.) Or to simulate a case where the null hypothesis is false:

```
y <- rexp(1000,1)
agostino.test(y)$p.value < 0.05 ## TRUE, reject
```

Comment: Hey Ben, thank you very much for your answer,  i need to the the null hypothesis that my steady returns have a zero skew. For that i need to take a confidence level from 95%. ( I just thought the agostino.test was a good solution for it).

Comment: I believe my answer does what you want. If you don't think it does, can you communicate (by editing your question or commenting) why not or what you find unclear?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example taken from https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/bootstrapping.html 
I made a small modification to use the skew statistic.  You don't provide a data set, so I just used the one in the example on the web page reference.

The following shows and example of getting a confidence interval for a skew statistic.  You can test a hypothesis using a CI if you check to see if the null value is in the confidence interval.

```
library(boot)
skew_f <- function(data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices] # allows boot to select sample
  return(e1071::skewness(d))
}


# bootstrapping with 1000 replications
results <- boot(data=faithful$eruptions, statistic=skew_f,
   R=1000)

boot.ci(results, type="bca")
```